# Need for enthalpy of vaporization in calculating bond dissociation enthalpy

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, physical-chemistry, bond, energy, enthalpy

In our chemical bonding class we were given the following problem:

> [image: Problem]

I am confused by how the question says that you need to consider the heat of vaporization/sublimation for HBr and HI.

> Bond dissociation enthalpy is defined as "the energy needed to break one mole of the bond to give separated atoms - everything being in the gas state."

So if you can find the heat of formation of that molecule in the gas phase, why would you need anything else?

My attempt:

> [image: Attempt]

The above answer obtained is not the one provided by the professor so I assume I'm missing something here. The answer provided is-

> 364 kJ/mol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I think that you have to look up the actual way bond dissociation enthalpy is defined in your textbook/lecture notes, since it is a not quite standard term. IUPAC [defines](http://goldbook.iupac.org/B00699.html) only bond-dissociation *energy* but *not* *enthalpy*.

> **bond-dissociation energy, $D$**
>
> The enthalpy (per mole) required to break a given bond of some
> specific molecular entity by homolysis, e.g. for $\ce{CH4 -> .CH3 + H.}$, symbolized as $D(\ce{CH3−H})$ (cf. heterolytic bond dissociation energy).

Many resources on the Internet claim that the IUPAC definition of the bond-dissociation energy refers to $\pu{0 K}$ (see e.g. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bond-dissociation_energy), [UC Davis ChemWiki](http://chemwiki.ucdavis.edu/Organic_Chemistry/Fundamentals/Homolytic_C-H_Bond_Dissociation_Energies_of_Organic_Molecules)) and that it differs from bond dissociation enthalpy, which refers to the enthalpy change *at room temperature ($\ce{298K}$)*.

**Wikipedia**

> The bond-dissociation energy is sometime also called the
> bond-dissociation enthalpy (or bond enthalpy), but these terms are not
> strictly equivalent, as they refer to the above reaction enthalpy at
> standard conditions, and differ from $D_0$ by about $\pu{1.5 kcal mol-1} \pu{(6
> kJ mol-1)}$ in the case of a bond to hydrogen in a large organic molecule.

**UC Davis ChemWiki**

> Officially, the IUPAC definition of bond dissociation energy refers to
> the energy change that occurs at $\pu{0 K}$, and the symbol is $D_0$. However,
> it is commonly referred to as BDE, the bond dissociation energy, and
> it is generally used, albeit imprecisely, interchangeably with the
> bond dissociation enthalpy, which generally refers to the enthalpy
> change at room temperature ($\pu{298K}$). Although there are technically
> differences between BDEs at $\pu{0 K}$ and $\pu{298 K}$, those difference are not
> large and generally do not affect interpretations of chemical
> processes.

If we follow this definitions, then yeah, at standard conditions $\ce{HBr}$ is liquid so we have to add up $\pu{12 kJ mol-1}$ for its enthalpy of vaporization, and (almost) get the desired $\pu{364 kJ mol-1}$. The small discrepancy is probably due to slightly wrong value of enthalpy of vaporization which I just quickly found somewhere.

Comment: Great thank you for your explanation. I believe you're correct as this yields the professor's answer

Comment: I think he wants it at 0 K which would make it a solid. If you take the heat of fusion and vaporization into account, the correct answer is given. Thanks again